# ¿Cómo llamo un atributo desde un main (if __name__ == '__main__')?

Tags: python, postgresql

soy nueva en programación y estoy haciendo un programa donde cargue un usuario y contraseña e imprima "Existe" o "No existe" dependiendo del Estado del usuario.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import null

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:649785@localhost/prueba') 
datos = declarative_base()

class ingresar(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ingresar, self).__init__()
        loadUi("ingreso.ui", self)
        self.botonIngresar.clicked.connect(ingresarFuncion.db)

class ingresarFuncion(datos):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password_db = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now())

    def __str__(self):
        usuario = self.usuario.text()
        password = self.password.text()
        return password, usuario
        
Session = sessionmaker(engine)
session = Session()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    datos.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    datos.metadata.create_all(engine)
    user1= ingresarFuncion(username = "camila", password_db = "camila")

    session.add(user1)
    session.commit()

    users = session.query(ingresarFuncion).filter(
        ingresarFuncion.username == ingresarFuncion.usuario
    ).filter(
       ingresarFuncion.password_db == ingresarFuncion.password
    )

    if users:
        print("Existe")
    else:
        print("No existe")

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow=ingresar()
widget =QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
widget.setFixedWidth(1200)
widget.setFixedHeight(600)
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

El problema es que no se cómo llamar a "usuario" y "password" que están dentro de la clase ingresarFuncion desde el main (donde supongo que "usuario" y "password" son atributos, pero no estoy segura, perdón si me he equivocado en el título), ya que cuando lo intento de la forma planteada me tira el siguiente error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Proyecto\main\main.py", line 45, in 
ingresarFuncion.username == ingresarFuncion.usuario
AttributeError: type object 'ingresarFuncion' has no attribute 'usuario'

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Tu clase `ingresarFuncion`  si tiene el atributo `username` el cual has definido dentro de la clase, pero no existe el atributo `usuario`, nunca has creado ese atributo

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda :D!